# ChessBoard X and Y coordinates into array

Tags: java, arrays, jpanel, mouseevent, containers

I am trying to point the x and y coordinates of a chessboard to specific array values. For example, x:145 y:347 should point to [3,1] on my chessboard. The Size of the chessboard is 460 by 460, however I am not sure what to do as far as calculations. The array is 8 by 8, which is the same as a chess board.

Code:

```
public Container c;
c = getContentPane();
setBounds(100,75,460,460);
public JPanel pnlMain = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
pnlMain.setBounds(2, 2, 460, 860);
c.add(pnlMain);

public void MousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    if(e.getX() < 460 && e.getY() < 460){
        int x = e.getX() / 57;
        int y = e.getY() / 175; 
    }
}
```

I am not getting the correct array location when debugging.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `e.getY() / 175`?

Comment: @Alejandro Yes sorry

Answer (score 0):

Since you said your chessboard was 460x460 it should be:

```
if(e.getX() < 460 && e.getY() < 460){
    int x = e.getX() / 57;
    int y = e.getY() / 57; 
}
```

Comment: I would think that too, but say if I am making my first move and i take one of my pawns at 145,347, 145/57 is fine but 347/57 gives me 6 which is the other players piece. I am assuming that the top left corner of the board is 0,0. Unless there is a way I can make it so the bottom left would be considered 0,0?

Comment: Are you sure the top left corner is 0,0? Put a System.out.print for the mouse click and make sure.

Comment: Just checked got 8,4 when I clicked at the top left. However, I just noticed my container is 460 by 460 however I added a Jpanel to that which is 460 by 860. Im guessing this would change the answer? The Jpanel just stretches out the way the board looks.